# create a github issue with github-create-issue and nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create an issue in a github repository and I found the github-create-issue npm nodule.
I tried to use the examples from the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-create-issue

my current code looks like this:

`var createIssue = require( 'github-create-issue' );`

`var opts = {
    'token': 'abcMYabcTOKEN!'
};`

`createIssue( 'noevazz/python_intro', 'Big bug.', opts, clbk );`

`function clbk( error, issue, info ) {
    console.log( issue );
}`

I know I can do it directly on github, but I need to create a lot of issues, so I'd like to create a little program to automate this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved it:
[github-create-issue](https://github.com/noevazz/github-create-issue/blob/master/crear_issues.js)